# debian ubuntu: most pager does not print the required foreground colors

Tags: ubuntu, colors, debian, pager

**Need**
Within a Debian/Ubuntu OS, I need to print (to STDOUT) a file with embed format interprated by the pager (I'm using "most") but it does not interpolate colors properly. All foreground colors appear white colored even if defined as black or red or green or whatever in the file. I can't find the pager setup to force the use of the file formats.

**Questions** :
Is there an option to force the pager "most" to using the file formats ?
or
Shall I use another pager (than currently "most") ?

**Some details** : myfile content example :

```
481\tparameter.foo.bar\t\033[1;32m\033[40m10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0, 172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0\t\033[1;31m\033[40m10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0,192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0\033[00m\n
```

***Works*** (colors are correctly interpreted when not using the pager)

```
echo -e $(cat myfile)
```

***Does not work*** (foreground colors appear white using the pager "most")

```
echo -e $(cat myfile) | most
```

or

```
echo -e $(cat myfile) | pager
```

Comment: `less` and `most` have the `-R` option "for the colors". But it's not compatible with `more`.

Comment: @nmichaels: yes, it works with echo -e $(cat myfile) | less -R, but it works as well w/o "less".  This is not what I'm expecting as I want the colored page to keep in editor, like it's the case using "most"

Comment: @shellholic: thx I did not know that option and even I could not find it in the man page. Anyway, using -R did not change the bad color interpreter (I have still white foreground colors using -R)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I devised to get file coloring in the shell.
First, install the package source-highlight

```
    alex@dionisos:wikimodels$ sudo apt-get install source-highlight
```

Then create a script named `colorcat` with the following content

```
    #!/bin/sh
    /usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh $*
```

and save it on your `$PATH`. I used `~/bin` for that but `/usr/local/bin` is also a good choice.

Make the `colorcat` script executable

```
    alex@dionisos:wikimodels$ chmod +x ~/bin/colorcat
```

And then just do

```
    alex@dionisos:wikimodels$ colorcat Comments.scala | most
```

and it will be shown with pretty colors.

You can also do

```
    alex@dionisos:wikimodels$ colorcat Comments.scala
```

for small files if you want.